# Loop through rows and columns to search for a value in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am looping through the data beginning at column 7 to last column (search range) looking for three(3) things based on column 3 and column 4 (i.e. Allele Call).

First, I'm looking for the exact matches of whatever value is in column 3 and column 4 across that row in columns with "Allele" as header i.e. columns 7,10,13 etc and once found, my code fills that cell with a color index plus the next two cell on the right (i.e. Allele, Size, Height columns as all these still pertain to the same allele call).

Secondly, I want the value that is minus 1 of the value in columns 3 and 4 e.g. if cells(i,3)=11, then I want to search for 10 still under the header "allele" (N.B. there is either one or no occurrence of this value) and then lastly I'm looking for the value that is plus 1 of the value in columns 3 or 4 e.g cells(i,4)=17 then I want to search for 18.

Then there is a 2nd method that is used to find the values on either side of the Allele call (column 3 and 4 values).  Instead of the minus 1 or plus 1 to that value (under the Allele header in search range),  I need to used the column adjacent to Allele, i.e. Size. To be precise, based on size, the variation of the Allele call and the next allele is 4. So if Allele 11 has size 100 then I'm looking for the allele with size 96 for the reverse Allele and 104 for the forward allele.

Since these values are decimals, I have a range of 3-5.
The colors: Actual match=Blue; Reverse Allele= Green; Forward Allele=Yellow.
Here is my code below and I have also attached a picture for clarity

[image: Proposed lookout]

```
ArrFS = Split("3 - 5", "-")
mnFS = CDbl(ArrFS(0))
mxFS = CDbl(ArrFS(1))


'loop through rows in first column
 For i = 2 To totN
'loop through columns
    For j = 7 To lastCol Step 3
    On Error Resume Next

    If shN.Cells(i, 3) = shN.Cells(i, j) Then
                Size = shN.Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 1)
    ElseIf shN.Cells(i, 4) = shN.Cells(i, j) Then
                Size = shN.Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 1)
    End If
     
    If shN.Cells(i, 2) = ("N/A") Then
        Resume Next

    'True Alleles=Blue (exact value in column 3 or 4)
    ElseIf shN.Cells(i, 3).Value = shN.Cells(i, j).Value Then
       shN.Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i, j + 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 41 '6
    ElseIf shN.Cells(i, 4) = "" Then
       shN.Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i, j + 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    ElseIf shN.Cells(i, 4) = shN.Cells(i, j) Then
       shN.Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i, j + 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 41 
    End If
        
       For K = 8 To lastCol Step 3
                      
            'Reverse Allele-Green (value in columns 3 or 4 minus 1 or within minus 3-5 size range)
            If shN.Cells(i, 3) = ("X") Or _
               shN.Cells(i, 4) = ("Y") Then
            Resume Next
            
                'search based on size range (minus 3-5)
            ElseIf ((shN.Cells(i, K) + mnFS) <= Size) And ((shN.Cells(i, K) + mxFS) >= Size) Or _
                shN.Cells(i, 3) - 1 = shN.Cells(i, j).Value Then
                shN.Range(Cells(i, K - 1), Cells(i, K + 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 35 Or _
                shN.Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i, j + 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 35 
                 ElseIf shN.Cells(i, 4) - 1 = shN.Cells(i, j).Value Then
                shN.Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i, j + 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 35 
            End If
       Next
    
            'Forward Allele=Yellow (value in columns 3 or 4 plus 1)
            If shN.Cells(i, 3) = ("X") Or _
                shN.Cells(i, 4) = ("Y") Then
            Resume Next
   
            ElseIf shN.Cells(i, 3) + 1 = shN.Cells(i, j) Then
                shN.Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i, j + 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 '6
            ElseIf shN.Cells(i, 4).Value + 1 = shN.Cells(i, j).Value Then
                shN.Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i, j + 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 '4
  
            End If
     
  Next

Next
```

Comment: So what problem(s) are you facing? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The task may be too complex to be contained in a single procedure. Therefore I would divide the structure into, perhaps, half a dozern subs and functions and a `Main` which just determines which functions to call. As each function has its own, limited scope of functionality you would be able to pinpoint where a problem is. That makes maintenance a lot easier and, therefore, less time consuming, which, in turn, qualifies it for getting help here.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the behaviour of "Resume Next" in your code. Its purpose is for error handling and it is valid only in an error handling procedure.  The way you have placed it in your code sample makes me think your intention is that it skips to the "Next" statement of the corresponding "For" loop.  If I understand correctly, I expect those "Resume Next" statements will be giving you an error.

Comment: @ Siddharth, the code takes forever to run and I'm struggling with using the size to find the forward allele. @ Variatus, I'm still new in vba so I'm not well versed in calling sub procedures hence the reason why I tend to cram the code.

Comment: To save time you should not works on the sheets. Try to use the stack/heap by using memory structures. Paste the range you want to work on into Variant/Dictionnary and loop in the Variant instead of searching on each cells. You will need to adapt your code but it will be ten times faster